# Подключение фортрановской LAPACK x64 в x64 проект на C#

Tags: c#, dll, extern

Имеется фортрановская библиотека LAPACK - пакет работы с линейной алгеброй. Конкретно в данный момент интересует её функция DGTSV (метод прогонки для трёхдиагональных матриц). Её сигнатура в фортране такая:

```
subroutine dgtsv (
integer N,
integer NRHS,
double precision, dimension( * ) DL,
double precision, dimension( * ) D,
double precision, dimension( * ) DU,
double precision, dimension( ldb, * ) B,
integer LDB,
integer INFO 
)
```

В компонентном паскале (он только 32-bit, поэтому версия LAPACK - тоже 32-bit) я подключал LAPACK таким образом (звездочка имеет смысл метки для видимости извне, аналог public в C#):

```
MODULE LinalgLAPACK ["liblapack.dll"];
PROCEDURE DGTSV* ["dgtsv_"] (VAR n : LAPACK_Integer; VAR nrhs : LAPACK_Integer;
      VAR dl : Double; VAR d : Double; VAR du : Double; VAR b : Double;
      VAR ldb : LAPACK_Integer; VAR info : LAPACK_Integer);
```

Тут есть нюанс - liblapack.dll требует libblas.dll, а еще libgfortran-3.dll, libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll и libquadmath-0.dll. Все они - 32-битные. Зависимости исследовались Dependency Walker'ом.

Поскольку в фортране ВСЕ аргументы передаются ТОЛЬКО по ссылке, поэтому аргументы-указатели на массивы заменены на ссылки на начальные элементы массивов. В основном модуле вызов выглядел так:

```
MODULE LinalgTest;
IMPORT LAPACK := LinalgLAPACK;
...
PROCEDURE Test*;
  VAR
    size, nrhs, info : INTEGER;
    c0, c1, c2, v : POINTER TO ARRAY OF REAL;
  BEGIN
    size := 3;
    nrhs := 1;
    NEW (c0, size);
    NEW (c1, size);
    NEW (c2, size);
    NEW (v, size);
    ...
    LAPACK.DGTSV (size, nrhs, c0[1], c1[0], c2[0], v[0], size, info);
  END Test;
```

Главная диагональ имеет длину size, над- и под- диагонали - соответственно size-1. Во избежание смещения индексов используется маленькая хитрость: по ссылке (а фортрановская DGTSV интерпретирует сcылку как указатель) передается элемент с индексом **1** из массива длиной **size**, а не элемент с индексом **0** из массива длиной **size - 1**. И все прекрасно работает...

Теперь пытаюсь проделать то же в C#. Используя скомпилированные в x64 .dll библиотеки - это x64 версия liblapack.dll, которая явно требует x64 версии libblas.dll, а неявно еще и libgfortran_64-3.dll, libgcc_s_seh_64-1.dll, libquadmath-0.dll, решил разобраться с простым консольным x64 приложением на C#.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Linalg
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("liblapack.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void dgtsv_(in int size1, in int nrhs, in double c0, in double c1, in double c2, in double v, in int size2, out int info);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 3;
            int nrhs = 1;
            double[] c0 = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
            double[] c1 = new double[] { 1.0, -2.0, 1.0 };
            double[] c2 = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
            double[] v = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
            int info = 0;
            dgtsv_(in size, in nrhs, in c0[1], in c1[0], in c2[0], in v[0], in size, out info);
            Console.WriteLine("info = {0}", info);
        }
    }
}
```

При запуске - System.BadImageFormatException: "Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат. (0x8007000B)"

Диспетчер конфигураций:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь проект:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Люди, добрые - что не так? )))

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110844/discussion-on-question-by-serg-tortilliani---lapack-x64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, я таки допинал C# и OpenBLAS. Малой кровью получилось с Visual Studio 2010 (32-битная версия). Пример реально работающей программы с 32-битными OpenBLAS и с референсными BLAS/LAPACK (пример честно стащил [отсюда](https://github.com/aidevnn/LapackCSharpTest) и совсем немного подправил *название библиотеки*):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace VAK_lapack_test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        //[DllImport("liblapack.dll", EntryPoint = "dgesv_")]
        [DllImport("libopenblas.dll", EntryPoint = "dgesv_")]
        static extern void lapack_dgesv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, double[] a, ref int lda, int[] ipvt, double[] b, ref int ldb, ref int infos);

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // 5X - 2Y = 7 
            // -X +  Y = 1
            double[] a = { 5, -1, -2, 1 };
            double[] b = { 7, 1 };

            int n = 2;
            int nrhs = 1;
            int lda = 2;
            int ldb = 2;
            int infos0 = 0;

            var a0 = a.ToArray();
            var b0 = b.ToArray();
            int[] ipvt0 = new int[n];

            lapack_dgesv(ref n, ref nrhs, a0, ref lda, ipvt0, b0, ref ldb, ref infos0);

            Console.WriteLine("Equations");
            Console.WriteLine("5X - 2Y = 7");
            Console.WriteLine("-X +  Y = 1");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Solutions netlib lapack");
            //Console.WriteLine($"X = {b0[0]} and Y = {b0[1]}");
            Console.WriteLine("X = {0} and Y = {1}", b0[0], b0[1]);
            Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
}
```

И самое главное. Это работает только с моими специально обученными библиотеками. Специальная обученность их заключается в том, что они собраны с помощью MinGW GCC 4.9 (Об особенностях этой версии можно немного почитать в официальном документе [How to use OpenBLAS in Microsoft Visual Studio](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio); но там не говорится, что это единственная возможность. Как я писал, это просто самый простой вариант в моих условиях).

Для 32-битных версий, теоретически, можно использовать динамические библиотеки от MinGW с верисями, новее чем gcc 4.7, но у меня почему-то это не вышло с более новыми версиями (имеются ввиду, версии MinGW GCC, которым я собирал библиотеку OpenBLAS). А вот для 64-битной версии, как я понял, других вариантов нет - библиотеки нужно собирать в самом Visual Studio.

Теперь, когда есть работающий пример, можно начинать искать набор библиотек, совместимых с VS (можно попробовать вот [отсюда](https://bitbucket.org/aperezrathke/vs-lapack/src/master/) - я не пробовал, это Яндекс подсказывает; но это оригинальные библиотеки с Netlib.org, а не OpenBLAS).

Comment: Маэстро, вы чудотворец - Буратино ожил ))) Я так понимаю есть три варианта решения - OpenBLAS с его LAPACK'ом, попытаться допилить оригинальный NetLib'овский LAPACK, а еще есть вариант с NuGet'овским LAPACK'ом - но я совсем не понял как его использовать в коде: using делать, очередной DllImport пилить или что?

Comment: @serg.tortilliani, я не знаю c# и всяких его NuGet'ов - тут я точно не помогу. Оригинальный LAPACK надо не допиливать, а просто найти и взять готовую сборку (если 64-битная сойдет, то я ссылку привел, осталось только проверить). Ну а с OpenBLAS... видимо еще нужны танцы с бубном (там рекомендуют к cmake прикрутить систему сборки анаконда, кажется).

Comment: Дык вот я с самого начала скачал с NetLib'а оригальные 64-битные dll'ки. Затем нашел _64 версии libgfortran_64-3.dll, libgcc_s_seh_64-1.dll, но этого оказалось мало для удовлетворения зависимостей - до кучи жахнул туда libgcc_s_seh-1.dll и libquadmath-0.dll не пойми-какой разрядности, но после этого VS перестала ругаться на Unknown DLL или как-там это... Оно собиралось, но при запуске всё та же ошибка - System.BadImageFormatException... Я поэтому и вопрос-то задал - что не так?

Comment: @serg.tortilliani, не так то, что 1) не ясно, какие версии этих библиотек и откуда Вы набрали - они могут оказаться несовместимы между собой; 2) MinGW и Visual Studio как-то не очень дружат, хотя системные библиотеки от винды MinGW вполне нормально использует; 3) все параметры функций должны передаваться по ссылке (причем, в том примере что я стащил проводятся какие-то странные сложные манипуляции с массивом; я не знаю что это значит, но так оно работает :-), хотя и 'динамический' массив там тоже используется ).

Comment: @serg.tortilliani, С OpenBLAS нужно просто аккуратно выполнить их инструкцию через анаконду и LLVM. А вот почему нельзя через один CMake собрать 64-битную версию они не объяснили :-(. Может, нет подходящего 64-битного фортрана (кроме LLVM). Не, ну есть еще от Intel, но он денег стоит... (да, OpenBLAS может собираться минут 20-30, если что).

Comment: Вышел на страницу https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio. Дошел до запуска из консоли анаконды vcvars64.bat, а у меня в VS2019 C++ вообще нет... Сижу-качаю...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110851/discussion-between-serg-tortilliani-and-vladimir).

Answer (score 1):

Огроменное спасибище Владимиру https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/248924/vladimir

Решение нашлось.

Сначала в VS2019 добавляем поддержку C++. Он в процессе потребуется и без файла vcvars64.bat не обойтись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаем всё по инструкции: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/wiki/How-to-use-OpenBLAS-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio

Качаем OpenBLAS c https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.3.10/ (https://sourceforge.net/projects/openblas/files/v0.3.10/OpenBLAS%200.3.10%20version.tar.gz/download)

Качаем и устанавливаем 64-битную миниконду со страницы https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html (https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe)

Все операции я проводил в корне C: - у меня это SSD. Создал папку C:\opt - она потребуется в дальнейшем. Распаковал архив с OpenBLAS и переименовал его в C:\OpenBLAS. Запускаем консоль анаконды "Anaconda Prompt (Miniconda3)" - я её запустил с правами администратора, на всякий - во избежание возможных проблем с правами на запись. Переходим в консоли в папку с OpenBLAS'ом:

```
cd\
cd openblas
```

В консоли отображается

```
(base) C:\OpenBLAS>
```

Все команды вводим в консоли. Поехали!

```
conda update -n base conda
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install -y cmake flang clangdev perl libflang
conda install -y -c isuruf kitware-ninja
```

Затем

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
```

Создаем в C:\OpenBLAS .bat-файл с таким содержимым (опция **-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON** обязательна). Я назвал его zx.bat:

```
set "LIB=%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\lib;%LIB%"
set "CPATH=%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library\include;%CPATH%"
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang-cl -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=flang -DBUILD_WITHOUT_LAPACK=no -DNOFORTRAN=0 -DDYNAMIC_ARCH=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

В консоли анаконды его запускаем:

```
zx
```

Переходим к самому главному и самому долгому:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

После окончания компиляции завершаем всё командой:

```
cmake --install . --prefix c:\opt -v
```

Забегая вперед - нужно ввести еще одну, самую последнюю команду :)

```
conda install libflang
```

Заходим в C:\opt\bin и видим свежеиспечённую openblas.dll. В 64-битном Dependency walker'е (он проживает по адресу https://www.dependencywalker.com/) можно увидеть зависимости этой dll. Нужны оказываются ещё и некие flang.dll и flangrti.dll, а сама flang.dll потребует libomp.dll. После команды **conda install libflang** они как раз установятся и найти их можно в папке "C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Miniconda3\Library\bin".

Теперь запускаем Visual Studio 2019 (ну у кого что), создаем консольное приложение. В диспетчере конфигурации сразу выставляем платформу x64.

Исходный код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Linalg
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("openblas.dll", EntryPoint = "dgtsv_")]
        static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, double[] c0, double[] c1, double[] c2, double[] v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 3;
            int nrhs = 1;
            double[] c0 = new double[] { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 };
            double[] c1 = new double[] { 1.0, -2.0, 1.0 };
            double[] c2 = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
            double[] v = new double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
            int info = 0;
            lapack_dgtsv (ref size, ref nrhs, c0, c1, c2, v, ref size, ref info);

            Console.WriteLine("info = {0}", info);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всем большое спасибо за участие.

Comment: @Vladimir Еще раз - огромное спасибо за ссылку на OpenBLAS и инструкцию по сборке.

Comment: Я удалил свои "ответы" с неудачными попытками прикрутить обычный LAPACK. Удалился и комментарий пользователя https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/294854/. Цитирую "вы не сможете загрузить 32 битную версию библиотеки в 64 битный процесс...", но суть то и была в том, что я пытался 64-битные зависимости 64-битными библиотеками компенсировать... Короче - не вышло, я нашел способ... а за попытку помочь  - спасибо...

Answer (score 1):

Выяснился еще один нюанс - в Компонентом Паскале (среда BlackBoox Component Builder) я использовал следующие конструкции.

При описании:

```
PROCEDURE DGTSV* ["dgtsv_"] (VAR n : LAPACK_Integer; VAR nrhs : LAPACK_Integer;
  VAR dl : Double; VAR d : Double; VAR du : Double; VAR b : Double;
  VAR ldb : LAPACK_Integer; VAR info : LAPACK_Integer);
```

При использовании:

```
LAPACK.DGTSV (size, nrhs, c0[1], c1[0], c2[0], v[0], size, info);
```

Обращаю внимание на **VAR dl, d, du, b : Double;** (**VAR** - указание на использование передачи по ссылке, а не по значению, аналог в c# - **ref**) - это не **dl, d, du, b : POINTER TO ARRAY OF Double;**. И при вызове стоят не указатели на массивы **c0, c1, c2, v**, а указатели на элементы массивов **c0[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbCc.png)], c1[0], c2[0], v[0]**. Причём, **c0[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbCc.png)]** - это указатель на элемент массива с индексом 1 (индексация с 0). К моему удивлению, если в исходнике C# Linalg подправить описание с

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, double[] dl, double[] d, double[] du, double[] v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
```

на

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, ref double dl, ref double d, ref double du, ref double v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
```

то и вызов можно сделать не

```
lapack_dgtsv (ref size, ref nrhs, c0, c1, c2, v, ref size, ref info);
```

а

```
lapack_dgtsv(ref size, ref nrhs, ref c0[1], ref c1[0], ref c2[0], ref v[0], ref size, ref info);
```

т.е. тот же трюк, что работал в Компонентном Паскале можно провернуть и тут (**c0[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbCc.png)]**)!!!

Итак, решаем одномерную стационарную задачу теплопроводности d2u/dx2 = 0 на трёх точках - да, это смешно, но это самый простой тест. Вторая производная аппроксимируется так: u[2] - 2*u[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbCc.png)] + u[0] = 0. Левое граничное условие - u[0] = 0, правое - u[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKbCc.png)] = 1. Матрица коэффициентов и прочее:

```
0 [1  0  0]     [u0]   [0]
  [1 -2  1]   * [u1] = [0]
  [0  0  1] 0   [u2]   [1]
```

Стационарное решение - прямая x = i/(N-1), где i = 0..2, N = 3, т.е. u = (0, 0.5, 1).
Нулевые элементы матрицы за пределами []-скобок - как бы продолжения над- и под-диагоналей.

Основная диагональ - (1, -2, 1). Нижняя диагональ - (1, 0), а с учетом дополнительного элемента (**0**, 1, 0). Аналогично - верхняя: (0, 1, **0**)

Дополнительные элементы как-бы не используются, но есть. Они позволяют избежать смещения индексов: с0[**i-1**] вместо желаемого с0[**i**].

```
с0[i-1] := a[i,i-1];
с1[i] := a[i,i];
с2[i] := a[i,i+1];
```

Исходный код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Linalg
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("openblas.dll", EntryPoint = "dgtsv_")]
        static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, ref double dl, ref double d, ref double du, ref double v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int size = 3;
            int nrhs = 1;
            double[] c0 = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
            double[] c1 = new double[] { 1.0, -2.0, 1.0 };
            double[] c2 = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
            double[] v = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
            int info = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("v = ({0}, {1}, {2})", v[0], v[1], v[2]);

            lapack_dgtsv(ref size, ref nrhs, ref c0[1], ref c1[0], ref c2[0], ref v[0], ref size, ref info);

            Console.WriteLine("info = {0}", info);
            Console.WriteLine("v = ({0}, {1}, {2})", v[0], v[1], v[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

И да - это работает!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как говорится: "Ничего не понял, но на всякий случай плюсанул". Вообще, это вполне можно было написать отдельной темой. Задать вопрос типа "Как сделать то-то с помощью lapack/openblas?" и самому тут же ответить. И принять потом свой ответ.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Я когда первый раз вопрос формулировал, ни про OpenBLAS ничего не знал, ни сборку из исходников никогда не делал (только свои программки)... А тут нашлись грамотные товарищи (конкретно - Владимир) - подсказали, ну а я только воспользовался подсказкой... Кроме того - все свои неудачные попытки я просто удалил из ответов... Поэтому создается впечатление, что сам задал вопрос и сам на него ответил )))

Comment: @Alexander Petrov А вообще такая практика - задать вопрос, самому на него ответить и принять ответ - приветствуется? Это же типа как накрутка самому себе престижа или как тут это называется...

Comment: Приветствуется. Если конечно, вопрос и ответ небанальные, типа Hello world.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Насчет - "Ничего не понял, но на всякий случай плюсанул"... Это, конечно, тема довольно специфическая - решение одно-, дву-, трёхмерных уравнений типа теплопроводности при помощи BLAS/LAPACK. Загадывать наперед не буду, но при возможности опубликую что-то подобное, естественно с картами и девчёнками )))

Comment: @Alexander Petrov А как насчет перевода на инглиш? Нашим западным партнерам это будет нужно? Думаю, что не я один с Лапакой в сишарпе бодаюсь...

Comment: Делать переводы тоже не возбраняется. Причём даже чужие вопросы-ответы можно переводить (с указанием авторства и ссылкой). Но, конечно, нельзя предугадать, заплюсуют или заминусуют.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Можно ещё вопрос? Про nuget. Я так и не понял как nuget'овский lapack в свой проект включить... using NetLib.LAPACK - не сработал... (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155305/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-nuget-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b5%d1%82-netlib-lapack-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%b2-vs2019)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov И да... Главная фишка, которую я обнаружил, состоит в том, что фортрановские, сишные и т.д. библиотеки, которые требуют указатели на массивы в аргументах можно слегка обхитрить... Передать, допустим, не указатель на начало массива диной N, а на элемент с индексом 1, т.е. как бы на массив диной N-1. Естественно, если при вызове массив такой длины и нужен. А в случае LAPACK.DGTSV - так и есть! Размер массива D равен N, а размеры DL и DU - N-1.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Да вообще можно строки двумерного массива (да хоть десятимерного) передавать в качестве аргумента - допустим A[i, 0]... Эту хитрость донести бы как-нибудь до сообщества - очень полезная штука в правильном контексте, понятно, что нельзя допускать выхода за границы массива, но если осторожно - то очень удобно!