# Как подключить nuget-пакет NetLib.LAPACK в c# проект в VS2019?

Tags: c#, nuget

Я понимаю - я полный нуб и чайник...
Nuget-пакет NetLib.LAPACK скачан и установлен - отображается в зависимостях... Что нужно сделать, чтобы его в своем проекте использовать?
using NetLib.LAPACK - не работает...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetLib.LAPACK/ просто полна полезной информации...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой акробатический трюк нужно исполнить, чтобы начать его использовать?

Comment: Вопрос очень странный, вы читали документацию по этой библиотеке? 
Библиотеки, которые вы используете в проекте должны быть указаны в блоке `using`. Вы указываете ссылку на пространство имен библиотеки и дальне начинаете использовать предоставленный функционал..

Comment: Я привел скриншоты - я, видимо, туплю - но не понимаю, а где документация-то находится... примеры программ...

Comment: Исчез мой комментарий... бесследно... Еще раз - using NetLib.LAPACK - не работает. Документация на странице https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetLib.LAPACK/ ну просто исчерпывающая... Это типа сарказм... Если можете подсказать ссылку на нормальную документацию и примеры рабочих программ - я вам буду благодарен...

Comment: Эта библиотека какая-то мутная. Документации нет, примеров нет. Похоже, она под какую-то конкретную архитектуру процессора собрана.

Comment: Количество скачиваний у неё крохотное. Если именно по загрузкам судить, то NLapack выглядит более обещающей. И сайт с примерами есть.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Спасибо за разъяснения! Я хотел с Лапаком на всех фронтах, так сказать, рассчитаться... Но версия OpenBLAS меня во всех отношениях устраивает, сборка прошла хоть и долго, но без единой ошибки. И теперь смело могу эту весёлую компанию - openblas.dll, flang.dll, flangrti.dll, libomp.dll - рекомендовать всем... ))) Еще раз - спасибо за участие.