# Как при помощи x64 версии OpenBLAS/LAPACK решать стационарные уравнения теплопроводности?

Tags: c#, dll, численные-методы, extern

Итак - x64-версия библиотеки OpenBLAS.dll прекрасно подключилась в x64 c#-проект ([Подключение фортрановской LAPACK x64 в x64 проект на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155157/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-lapack-x64-%D0%B2-x64-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/1155592)). Как же теперь с её помощью решать стационарные (и даже нестационарные, и даже неодномерные) уравнения теплопроводности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenBLAS/LAPACK x64 успешно подключен и проверен ([Подключение фортрановской LAPACK x64 в x64 проект на C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155157/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-lapack-x64-%D0%B2-x64-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c/1155592)). Приступим-с...

Пример, приведенный в собственном ответе на вопрос о подключении x64 LAPACK был таков - стационарное уравнение теплопроводности d2u/dx2 = 0 с граничными условиями u(0) = 0 = u0, u(1) = 1 = u1. Задача решалась на трех точках и вся система уравнений выглядела так:

```
v[0] = 0.0 //левое граничное условие
v[1] - 2*v[1] + v[2] = 0.0 //конечно-разностный аналог второй производной d2u/dx2 с точностью до множителя 1/dx^2
v[2] = 1.0 //правое граничное условие
```

Давайте же решим задачу для произвольного **N** (**M = N - 1**). После дискретизации дифференциального уравнения в частных производных мы получаем систему линейных уравнений (вот зачем нам и нужен Linear Algebra PACKage = LAPACK) с матрицей коэффициентов и вектором правых частей:

```
|1  0  0  0  0  0  0 | |u[0]  |   |u0|
|1 -2  1  0  0  0  0 | |u[1]  |   |0 |
|0  1 -2  1  0  0  0 | |u[i-1]|   |0 |
|0  0  1 -2  1  0  0 |*|u[i]  | = |0 |
|0  0  0  1 -2  1  0 | |u[i+1]|   |0 |
|0  0  0  0  1 -2  1 | |u[M-1]|   |0 |
|0  0  0  0  0  0  1 | |u[M]  |   |u1|
```

Матрица, как видим - трёхдиагональная. Для работы с такими матрицами в фортрановском LAPACK'е существует специальная функция DGTSV с большим набором аргументов, каждый из которых передается только по ссылке, т.е. в Фортране вообще нельзя **CALL MYSUB (0)** - только **CALL MYSUB (x)**. Для совместимости фортрановские библиотеки пишутся на диалекте, который был ещё при динозаврах, а исходный код без компиляции исполняется на абаках и счётах... А тому человеку, который двинул в массы идею, что Фортран - лучший язык для математических расчётов, хочется сказать много "доброго" и "светлого"... Просто посмотрите исходники на **NetLib** - https://www.netlib.org/lapack/, например DGTSV (https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/d62/group__double_g_tsolve_ga2bf93f2ddefa5e671866eb2191dc19d4.html).

Тем не менее, эти библиотеки работают. А написаны они вручную в бинарном коде или на Брейнфаке - значения не имеет. Главное - чтобы работали быстро и без проблем подключались.

Разберём немного подробнее алгоритм решения. Вторая производная в точке **i** аппроксимируется как

```
d2v_dx2[i] = (dv_dx[i + 1/2] - dv_dx[i - 1/2])/dx;
d2v_dx2[i] = ((v[i + 1] - v[i])/dx - (v[i] - v[i - 1])/dx)/dx;
d2v_dx2[i] = (v[i + 1] - 2*v[i] + v[i - 1])/(dx*dx);
```

Для стационарной задачи d2u/dx2 = 0, т.е. dx можно и сократить, но желательно оставить - он пригодится в дальнейшем для решения задач нестационарных.

LAPACK.DGTSV требует передачи в качестве аргументов трех диагоналей матрицы коэффициентов: нижнюю (поддиагональ) - **DL** длиной **N-1**, главную - **D** длиной **N**, верхнюю (наддиагональ) - **DU** длиной **N-1**. Выделим диагонали **DL**, **D**, **DU** в явном виде. А затем дополним их внешними элементами и  сформируем трёхстрочную матрицу **c[3, N]**. Почему двумерный массив **c[3, N]**, а не три одномерных **c0[N]**, **c1[N]**, **c2[N]**? А вот заодно и проверим совместимость строк двумерного массива с одномерным.

```
0 |1  0  0  0  0  0  0 |
  |1 -2  1  0  0  0  0 |
  |0  1 -2  1  0  0  0 |    DU =   |0  1  1  1  1  1| 0       c|2| = |0  1  1  1  1  1  0|
  |0  0  1 -2  1  0  0 | -> D  =   |1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  1|   -> c|1| = |1 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2  1|
  |0  0  0  1 -2  1  0 |    DL =    0 |1  1  1  1  1  0|      c|0| = |0  1  1  1  1  1  0|
  |0  0  0  0  1 -2  1 |
  |0  0  0  0  0  0  1 | 0
```

Зачем включать дополнительные элементы? По очень простой причине - DGTSV вызывается в единственном месте, а коэффициенты могут модифицироваться в разных местах исходного кода. Поэтому вместо смещённых индексов

```
c[0, i - 1] = 1;
c[1, i] = -2;
c[2, i] = 1;
```

лучше иметь несмещённые

```
c[0, i] = 1;
c[1, i] = -2;
c[2, i] = 1;
```

Это и эстетичней, и потенциальные проблемы из-за забывчивости устраняет. А еще будет полезно для случая граничных условий четвёртого рода - циклических.

Для расширенных диагоналей **c[3, N]** описание и вызов функции DGTSV модифицируется. Вместо

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, double[] dl, double[] d, double[] du, double[] v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
lapack_dgtsv(ref size, ref nrhs, c[0], c[1], c[2], v, ref size, ref info);
```

имеем

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, ref double dl, ref double d, ref double du, ref double v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
lapack_dgtsv(ref size, ref nrhs, ref c[0, 1], ref c[1, 0], ref c[2, 0], ref v[0], ref size, ref info);
```

Еще раз. Было:

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(... double[] dl, double[] d, double[] du, double[] v ...);
lapack_dgtsv(... c[0], c[1], c[2], v ...);
```

Стало:

```
static extern void lapack_dgtsv(... ref double dl, ref double d, ref double du, ref double v ...);
lapack_dgtsv(... ref c[0, 1], ref c[1, 0], ref c[2, 0], ref v[0] ...);
```

Т.е. мы передаем ссылки, которые и указатели, не на массивы, а на элементы массивов. И поскольку для DGTSV первый элемент строки **c[0]**, т.е. **c[0, 0]** - не нужен, мы передаем ему указатель на второй элемент - **c[0, 1]** (**sic!!!**).

Теперь можно перейти и к исходному коду:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Parabolic
{
  class Program
  {
      [DllImport("openblas.dll", EntryPoint = "dgtsv_")]
      static extern void lapack_dgtsv(ref int n, ref int nrhs, ref double dl, ref double d, ref double du, ref double v, ref int ldb, ref int info);
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          // уравнение имеет вид d2u/dx2 = 0, u(0) = u0, u(1) = u1
          int size = 10 + 1; //количество точек
          int maxInd = size - 1; //максимальный индекс
          double dx = 1.0 / maxInd; //шаг сетки
          double dxSqrInv = 1.0 / (dx*dx); //обратный квадрат шага
          int nrhs = 1; //количество правых частей - нужно для lapack
          int info = 0; //код успешности выполнения - нужно для lapack
          double[,] c = new double[3, size]; //матрица коэффициентов
          double[] v = new double[size]; //искомая величина
          double v0 = 0.0; //левое граничное условие
          double v1 = 1.0; //правое граничное условие

          int i = 0;
          c[0, i] = 0.0;
          c[1, i] = 1.0;
          c[2, i] = 0.0;
          v[i] = v0;

          for (i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
          {
              double x = i / maxInd;
              c[0, i] = dxSqrInv;
              c[1, i] = -2.0 * dxSqrInv;
              c[2, i] = dxSqrInv;
              v[i] = 0.0;
          }

          i = maxInd;
          c[0, i] = 0.0;
          c[1, i] = 1.0;
          c[2, i] = 0.0;
          v[i] = v1;

          //важно: указан c[0, 1], а не c[0, 0]
          lapack_dgtsv(ref size, ref nrhs, ref c[0, 1], ref c[1, 0], ref c[2, 0], ref v[0], ref size, ref info);

          for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
              Console.Write("{0:F} ", v[i]); //ожидаем увидеть 0.00, 0.10, 0.20, ... 0.90, 1.00
          }
          Console.WriteLine();
          Console.WriteLine ("v[0] = {0} ", v[0]);
      }
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требует пояснения ожидаемое v[0] = 0.00 и имеемое v[0] = -0.00. Я вывел в конце неокруглённое значение и оно равно -2.8421709430404013E-16. Разные версии LAPACK могут выдать разные результаты, но вы таки поверьте, что -2.84/10000000000000000 таки практически равно 0.00 и пусть таки минус вас не беспокоит... )))

to be continued...

надеюсь... ))