# Как конвертировать c/c++ заголовочные .h файлы для OpenBLAS/LAPACK в c# библиотеку

Tags: c#, unity3d, численные-методы, dllimport

Начнем с того, что lapack.h содержит 13 717 строк и описание 1 828 функций. Вручную заменить каждое с/с++ описание

```
#define LAPACK_cbbcsd LAPACK_GLOBAL(cbbcsd,CBBCSD)
void LAPACK_cbbcsd(
    char const* jobu1, char const* jobu2, char const* jobv1t, char const* jobv2t, char const* trans,
    lapack_int const* m, lapack_int const* p, lapack_int const* q,
    float* theta,
    float* phi,
    lapack_complex_float* U1, lapack_int const* ldu1,
    lapack_complex_float* U2, lapack_int const* ldu2,
    lapack_complex_float* V1T, lapack_int const* ldv1t,
    lapack_complex_float* V2T, lapack_int const* ldv2t,
    float* B11D,
    float* B11E,
    float* B12D,
    float* B12E,
    float* B21D,
    float* B21E,
    float* B22D,
    float* B22E,
    float* rwork, lapack_int const* lrwork,
    lapack_int* info );
```

на c#

```
[DllImport("openblas.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "cbbcsd_")]
public static void CBBCSD(
    ref char jobu1, ref char jobu2, ref char jobv1t, ref char jobv2t, ref char trans,
    ref int m, ref int p, ref int q,
    ref float theta,
    ref float phi,
    ref complex_float U1, ref int ldu1,
    ref complex_float U2, ref int ldu2,
    ref complex_float V1T, ref int ldv1t,
    ref complex_float V2T, ref int ldv2t,
    ref float B11D,
    ref float B11E,
    ref float B12D,
    ref float B12E,
    ref float B21D,
    ref float B21E,
    ref float B22D,
    ref float B22E,
    ref float rwork, ref int lrwork,
    ref int info );
```

сами понимаете - то еще удовольствие :)

Comment: Это точно не проблема XY? Заменять вручную сорцы кажется странным решением

Comment: Цитирую сам себя - "Может есть решение проще - подскажите"

Comment: Проблема XY означает, что в принципе задача поставлена криво. Зачем вам "конвертировать c/c++ заголовочные .h файлы ... в c# библиотеку"? Может быть, вы хотите вызывать функции из этих библиотек в c# коде или что-то такое?

Comment: @dIm0n Хочу - и все сразу! Вы, видимо, - не вникли в проблему и не смотрели исходники...

Comment: @dIm0n Объясняю подробно - хочу как #Include "OpenBlas.h"... Попробуйте мне запретить... Хочу using Linalg - имею! Я хочу Linalg как корень - а  BLAS и LAPACK - как ветви... Имею! Хочу LAPACK.DGTSV - имею! Какой-такой XY - вы о чём вообще?

Comment: И да - я вызываю фортрановскик функции из фортрановской .dll при помощи с/c++ .h файла, который я сконвертировал в библиотеку классов (.dll), которые импортировал как public extern void, а затем так же public'ом их экспортировал, но уже как код .net

Comment: Ну - что-бы еще понятней было... Я  просто сделал свою x64 Linalg64.dll, которую можно  при помощи using Linalg подключить и, используя пространства имен Linalg.BLAS и Linalg.LAPACK, вызывать фортрановские LAPACK.DGTSV, например... Где тут XY - ткните мне пальцем, я сего не зрю... бревна в очах не чую...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может есть решение проще - подскажите. Я же использовал LibreOfficeCalc, Notepad++ и чуточку PuntoSwitcher.

Для начала создадим в VS проект-заготовку dll:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Linalg
{
    public static class LAPACK
    {

    }
}
```

Затем откроем lapack.h в Notepad++ и заменим все пробелы на табуляции. Удаляем всё, вплоть до первого define'а функции и пустой строки перед ним.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копируем всё в LibreOfficeCalc, выбрав в качестве разделителя знак табуляции. Именуем каждый столбец каким-либо образом - я пронумеровал 1, 2, 3 и протянул на 64 колонки (с запасом). Затем включил **Данные-Быстрый фильтр**. Но фильтр закончит работать там, где в первой колонке есть пустая ячейка. Поэтому заменяем пустые ячейки на уникальную последовательность, у меня это  - "**************".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выделяем столбец B и комбинацией Alt+Pause (при запущенном PuntoSwitcher'е) инвертируем регистр текста. Было "LAPACK_cbbcsd(", стало "lapack_CBBCSD(". Сразу же делаем замену в столбце B всех "lapack_" на "". Соглашение об именовании функций как-бы намекает, что их имена должны начинаться с заглавных сиречь прописных. Теперь вместо "LAPACK_cbbcsd(" имеем "CBBCSD(". Далее фильтруем define'ы и очищаем все столбцы, кроме первого. Снимаем фильтр - смотрим результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Опять включаем фильтр по define'ам. И вместо первого define'а (в ячейку A2) вводим формулу

```
="[DllImport(""openblas.dll"", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = """&СТРОЧН(B3)&"_"")]"
```

Получаем

```
[DllImport("openblas.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "cbbcsd(_")]
```

Протягиваем формулу до 13 586-ой строки. Отключаем фильтр.

Имена функций пока некорректные - "cbbcsd(_", а должно быть просто "cbbcsd_". Символ подчеркивания обязателен - именно так экспортированы функции в OpenBLAS.dll - в этом можно убедиться при помощи Dependency Walker'а (https://www.dependencywalker.com/). Но всё это легко правится в дальнейшем заменой (_")] на _")]. Осталось сделать обратную замену в столбце А строк "**************" на "".

Теперь можно выделить всё и скопировать обратно в Notepad++. Делаем замену табуляций обратно на пробелы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почти готово. Делаем замену

```
void
```

на

```
public static extern void
```

Есть соблазн сразу заменить

```
float*
double*
```

на

```
ref float
ref double
```

но тут спешить не нужно. Сначала меняем

```
complex_float*
complex_double*
```

на

```
ref complex_float
ref complex_double
```

иначе получим всякие

```
complex_ref float
complex_ref double
```

Ну зачем усложнять себе жизнь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В общем - довольно быстро удалось сделать проект библиотеки Linalg c LAPACK'ом и BLAS'ом с их внутренними пространствами имен. Результат - на https://github.com/SergioTortilliani/Linalg (я туда хотел залить рабочие x64 версии flang.dll, flangrti.dll, libomp.dll, openblas.dll - но github.com отказался загружать openblas.dll из-за размера). Библиотека Linalg вполне рабочая, но есть несколько моментов, которые хотелось бы обсудить.

Например, конструкцию вида

```
typedef lapack_logical (*LAPACK_S_SELECT2) ( const float*, const float* );
```

я интерпретировал как

```
public delegate LOGICAL S_SELECT2 (ref float a, ref float b);
```

чтобы можно было потом

```
public static int Select2(ref float a, ref float b)
{
    if (a > b)
  {
      return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

передавать в качестве аргумента, например, в SGEES. Будет ли работать ссылка на делегат как указатель на cdecl-функцию для callback-вызова? Мне это пока неизвестно...

Тем не менее, слегка изменённый тест из ([Как при помощи x64 версии OpenBLAS/LAPACK решать стационарные уравнения теплопроводности?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1158101/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-x64-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b8-openblas-lapack-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be)) вполне работоспособен:

```
using System;
using Linalg;

namespace Parabolic
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         // уравнение имеет вид d2u/dx2 = 0, u(0) = u0, u(1) = u1
         int size = 10 + 1; //количество точек

         ...

         LAPACK.DGTSV(ref size, ref nrhs, ref c[0, 1], ref c[1, 0], ref c[2, 0], ref v[0], ref size, ref info);

         for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
         {
             Console.Write("{0:F} ", v[i]); //ожидаем увидеть 0.00, 0.10, 0.20, ... 0.90, 1.00
         }
         Console.WriteLine();
         Console.WriteLine ("v[0] = {0} ", v[0]);
     }
   }
}
```

И, кстати, - да... Это работает в Unity. Пруф:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]